# How to accept recurring payments from buyers who don’t have a PayPal account?

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout, recurring-billing

"Paypal: Recurring payments via Express Checkout without user having to have a paypal account"
We have Website Payment Pro activated on our profile... How can we allow our customers to subscribe for recurring payments without a need to create paypal account?
we are using express checkout methods and create recurring profile(Using php)
but paypal always asks to login or signup which we do not force our customers to create account.

Any helpful information would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I think you need a paypal account for recurring payments.

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/ph/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside

Comment: Looks like a duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905104/how-to-implement-paypal-recurring-payment-api-with-option-for-buyers-to-pay-by-c