# How to Implement Paypal Recurring Payment API With option for buyers to pay by credit/debit cards php?

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment, recurring

Please, if someone has worked on it, I need help I have an enterprise application on which i need to implement this functionality. Initially I implemented Express checkout paypal API to create recurring payments but it doesn't allow users to pay without having paypal account but I'm confused on how to make paypal account optional for buyers to let them pay by credit/debit card too while creating recurring profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when working with recurring payments in Express Checkout the buyer will have to create or sign in to an account.

To provide direct credit card options for recurring payments you'll need to sign up for Payments Pro + Recurring Billing.

PayPal charges $30/mo for Pro by itself, and another $30/mo for the Recurring Billing functionality to be added to this.

That said, if you [contact me directly](https://www.angelleye.com/contact-us) I can get you in touch with somebody that can waive the $30/mo fee for Pro.  Not sure if he can do the same for the recurring fee, but he might be able to.

Depending on which version of Pro you get setup with you'll use either the PayFlow API or DoDirectPayment / CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.  You'll build a credit card checkout into your own site, and POST directly to the API.